# How to align columns with multiple Tkinter checkbuttons?

Tags: python, tkinter

I try to put sixteen checkbuttons into frame, placing them into four columns like:

```
c1 = Tkinter.Checkbutton(group.interior(), text = 'Name', indicatoron= 1, variable = self.Checkvar_nr, command=cb)
    c1.(row = 0, column = 0)
```

and so on up to:

```
c16.(row = 3, column = 3)
```

Everything's fine except columns vertical alignment because of the differences in the length of the text used.
How to align then horizontally?

Comment: also: `c1.grid(row=0,column=0)` instead of `c1.(row=0, column=0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't quite understand the problem, since columns *must* be vertically aligned since it's a grid. I think what you're saying is that the items in each column aren't aligned to a column boundary. Try using `sticky='w'` when adding each checkbutton to the grid. This will cause them to "stick" to the left edge of the column.

Comment: That's exactly what was my question about. Thanks a lot, your small hint works!

Answer (score 1):

As an option, try placing each element in a non-stretchable graphic element.

The thought is that the layout manager is maximizing the use of the screen real estate.  Because you want to take up more space, which is contrary to the layout manager's algorithm,  you will need to find a graphic container that doesn't "change size".

Sometimes you can do this through manually editing the text string (less preferred).  Other times you can use a `table` like structure (HTML for instance).  Other times you can use a frame with defined width and height attributes.  These frames are then placed inside of the columns as elements.

Note: It's been a long time since I played with Tk.  I'm going by memory.  Best of luck!

(edit:) Going from memory, the columns will adjust their width based on content.  If there are several three character labels in the first column and five character labels in the second column, the width of the two columns will be different. (Note: This will be depended on the layout manager.) If there is a 'fixed width' option for the layout manager in question, then it should keep all column widths the same.

With layout managers that rearrange with dimensions based on content (HTML, CSS, etc), it is sometimes necessary to place the content inside "immovable" containers.  Usually these are frames.  The frames work as bounding boxes.  This approach works when the element that needs to have a width and height does not have that feature.

Comment: I've used tk and Tkinter for a couple decades and I can't understand your answer. What do you mean by a "non-stretchable graphic element" or "graphic container"? Those terms don't really mean anything in the context of Tkinter. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "HTML for instance" since Tkinter doesn't support HTML. Plus, he's already using a table-like structure because he's using `grid`. I think your answer would be better if you were a bit more precise in your terminology.